# Fetching List of int from controller to View ASP.NET

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to fetch a set of data from controller to view, I have the following;

Index.cshtml

```
<input type="button" value="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="btnGet" name="btnGet" onclick="displayCalendar()" />
```

Upon pressing the button, the `displayCalendar()` function calls the jQuery fullCalendar which populates all the events from the controller.

The problem is that I have a set of integers that I also want to be fetched in that AJAX call or separately.

Controller:

```
 return Json(totalList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Now what have I tried?
I tried using ViewBag, ViewData, TempData. like this;

```
        TempData["countWeekDays"] = countWeekDays;
        TempData["countPresents"] = countPresents;
        TempData["countAbsence"] = countAbsence;
        TempData["countLates"] = countLates;
        TempData["countFines"] = countFines;
```

and then display them in the same Index.cshtml but it did not work. I, then made a list of integers and tried to bind that list along with the already list of objects that was passed in the json like;

```
        List<int> statsView = new List<int>();
        statsView.Add(countWeekDays);
        statsView.Add(countPresents);
        statsView.Add(countAbsence);
        statsView.Add(countLates);
        statsView.Add(countFines);

  IEnumerable<object> completeObjects = totalList.Cast<object>().Concat(statsView.Cast<object>());


    return Json(completeObjects, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

When I tried the above method, I could see the list in the console debug in the browser but the problem is that it doesnt populate the calendar then. if I exclude the list `statsView` then the calendar is properly populated with the events.

Maybe a function within the `displayCalendar()` that is when called, it fetches the list from the controller and simply displays it in the view?

UPDATED:

```
<div id='calendar'></div>
@section scripts{
    <script>
        function h() {
            id = $('#EmpId').val();

            s = $("#startDate").val();
            e = $("#endDate").val();


                $.post("/Controller/method",
                    {
                        ENum: id,
                        StartDate: s,
                        EndDate: e
                    },
                    function (response) {
                        callCalendar(response);
                    }
                 );
        }
        function displayCalendar(e)
        {

            $("#calendar").fullCalendar('removeEvents');
            $("#calendar").fullCalendar('addEventSource', e);
            $("#calendar").fullCalendar('rerenderEvents');

            $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                header: {
                    left: 'prev,next today',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: 'month,agendaDay'
                },
  }
            });
            //stats here
        }
    </script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            displayCalendar('');
        });
    </script>
}
```

Comment: Can you share the code which displays list of integers in calendar? What is the code of displayCalendar method?

Comment: How are you using the data inside the ajax success/done event ?

Comment: Why are u returning Jason? Return a partial view.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya I am not displaying the list on the calendar, the calendar is being populated with other data. I have a list of int type that I want to display just below the calendar but I dont know how to since the method is already returning json (for calendar).

Comment: @Shyju that is being done correctly and rendering fine. Right now we have a list as shown above `statsView` that I want to display on the view. (debugged, the values are in it just not being able to take to the view)

Comment: @alikuli I am returning json for fullcalendar.

Comment: you can return a an anonymous object with 2 properties. then update your client side code to use the specific property

Comment: @Shyju I updated the code that is used to take all the json return values and the calendar is populated. How do I return the list now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your current code is working to correctly populate the calendar and if you want to send some additional data (list of integers), you may return a new annonymous object with 2 properties, one for your original data and second for the additional data.

```
List<int> statsView = new List<int>();
statsView.Add(countWeekDays);
statsView.Add(countPresents);
statsView.Add(countAbsence);
statsView.Add(countLates);
statsView.Add(countFines);

return Json(new { list = totalList, statusList = statsView },
                                                     JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Now make sure you update the client side code to use the `list` property of the response object for your `callCalendar` method call. To get the statusView collections, use the `statusList` property of the response object.

```
var d = { ENum: id, StartDate: s, EndDate: e };
$.post("/Controller/method",d ,function (response) {
        console.log(response.statusList); 
        callCalendar(response.list);
});
```

If you want to display the items in response.statusList in the page, you may loop through them and add it to any existing DOM element. You can use `$.each` for iterating the array.

```
$.post("/Controller/method",d ,function (response) {
        console.log(response.statusList); 

        var items="";
        $.each(response.statusList,function(a,b){
           items+='<p>'+b+'</p>';
        });
        $("#StatusList").html(items);

        callCalendar(response.list);
});
```

Assuming you have a div with id set to `StatusList` in your page

```
<div id="StatusList"></div>
```

Comment: Same problem, I get the int list but the calendar does not populate with this, If I change the json return to the back it populates fine but i cant get the list then. Image > https://ibb.co/kb3aVG PS. the int list has nothing to do with calendar I just want to display it plain format maybe in a table.

Comment: the `response.list` will be same array as the array returned by your old code . If your old code worked fine,this should also works fine as long as you use `response.list`. compare the two outputs and see what is missing.

Comment: Also, the `JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet` has to be second parameter, not part of the anonymous object( I missed the bracket earlier,Fixed now)

Comment: I do not know what your `callCalendar` method does, hence cannot tell you what is wrong. But like i mentioned in my earlier comment, If your previous approach worked fine, all you need to do is compare the data in two approaches. As long as the `response` from previous approach and `response.list` are returning the same type of data (the array of items), your code should work fine.

Comment: `Now make sure you update the client side code to use the list property of the response object`  read this line again and now I fixed the calendar population. How do I display the statusList on the page now? > `console.log(response.statusList);`

Comment: If I uncomment any of this line it only displays the int list not the calendar `callCalendar(response.list);
                        console.log(response.statusList);
                        //displaySummary(response.statusList);
                        //document.write(response.statusList);`

Comment: I do not know what your displaySummay method does. Take a minute to go through the code in my answer. It is very simple. Simply looping through the items and creating a `p` tag for each item in the list and finally setting the list of `p` tags to the div with Id `StatusList`

Comment: Perfect! just one quickie, can I add some custom strings before each element in the list?

Comment: Why don't you try it ? :)

Comment: `items+='<p>'+b+'</p>';` this is concatenating them so I cannot add a uique string before each element. Like Hello: 22 World: 22 Have a good day: 06 ..etc

Comment: `items+='<p> You can add whatever you want here '+b+' or even here</p>';`

Comment: ^I tried that, the problem is that this will be same for all the elements. I want different strings for different elements in the list.

Comment: Then send a list of strings (with whatever unique value you want) from the controller instead of list of ints.

Comment: you mean a list of strings and ints combined?

Comment: It is up to you. You can create a simple class with an int property and string property and send a list of that. In your $.each loop, you will access it like `items+='<p>'+b.Name+':'+b.Id+'</p>';`